# Tishadow failed to start server on port 3000

Tags: appcelerator, tishadow

I'm on Mac OS and I got this error

```
ERROR: Failed to start server on port: 3000
```

I trier >>tishadow clear, but doesn't do anithing.
So I can't user tishadow anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your Terminal window and Restart and then

try the command `$ts server`

or `$ tishadow server --port 3001` it will start your server on 3001 port.